# Shadows in React-Three-Fiber working but cropped in rectangular region for no reason

Tags: three.js, shadow, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei, directional-light

Hi my problem is the following:
I successfully added shadows to my viewport but those seemed to be cropped inside a certain region. Thank you for your help :-)

- [with crop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2q0V.png)
- [region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5Faz.png)

```html
<Canvas colorManagement shadows>
        <ambientLight intensity={0.1} />
        <directionalLight intensity={0.5} position={[80, 80, 30]} castShadow />
        <OrbitControls />
        <Box castShadow receiveShadow args={[1, 3, 30]} position={[0, 0.2, 0]}>
          <meshStandardMaterial attach="material" color="gray" />
        </Box>
        <Box
          castShadow
          rotation={[0, -Math.PI / 2, 0]}
          receiveShadow
          args={[1, 3, 30]}
          position={[0, 0.2, 0]}
        >
          <meshStandardMaterial attach="material" color="gray" />
        </Box>
        <Plane
          receiveShadow
          rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]}
          position={[0, -1, 0]}
          args={[100, 100]}
        >
          <meshStandardMaterial attach="material" color="white" />
        </Plane>
      </Canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, a `DirectionalLight` shadow uses an orthographic camera to calculate the region where it casts shadows. This camera has `left, right, top, bottom` attributes set to `[-5, 5]` units by default. Your `Box` objects are larger than this, so they only cast shadows in the region within the light's shadow-camera. You need to modify your light shadow's camera dimensions to be big enough to fit your objects. For example:

```
light.shadow.camera.left = -20;
```

In react-three-fiber, you would achieve the same, by accessing the required property via a [kebab-case](https://www.theserverside.com/definition/Kebab-case) prop.

```
<directionalLight castShadow shadow-camera-left={-20} />
```

You can read more about the light's camera dimensions [in the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=shadow#api/en/lights/shadows/DirectionalLightShadow.camera)

Additionally, you [could add a `DirectionalLightHelper`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=direc#api/en/helpers/DirectionalLightHelper) to your `DirectionalLight` to better visualize the region of this shadow-camera.

Comment: `<directionalLight intensity={0.5} position={[80, 80, 30]} castShadow shadow-camera-left={-20} shadow-camera-right={20} shadow-camera-top={20} shadow-camera-bottom={-20} />` in react three fiber worked great THX!

Answer (score -2):

In my point of view, just add a class to the canvas and apply CSS. Give it a width of 100vw and height of 100vh. This show start working and you will be able to see the whole.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34832824)